# Can't access iTunes Music store from OS X

Tags: macos, itunes, itunes-store

So it used to work.  Here's what I'm trying...  now if I post the string in the browser it correctly opens to the right song in the browser.  But alas the code opens the iTunes but fails to open the album or song.

I'm using Yosemite 10.10.4 and iTunes 12.2.1.16.

```
maciTunesStr = @"itunes.apple.com/us/album/allegro-from-prelude-fugue/id982291206?i=982291615";
[self showProductPageForID:maciTunesStr];
```

THANKS!!!

Comment: Do you need to add `http://` or `https://` to your URL? `https://itunes.apple.com/us/...`

Comment: Sorry, no that didn't fix it.  I tried both persuasions and got back a message from iTunes both times saying "some kinda error occurred."  In other words, it didn't like either of them.  Thanks for the idea!!  Any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

well the following worked, but halfway.  It opens a browser window with the song highlighted.  This isn't the same as opening the iTunes app itself, but about 60% as good.  I would still appreciate a better answer but for now this will suffice.

This is the most modern link format I got from the iTunes link maker.
https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com

```
    musicDownloadLink = ["https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/sonata-in-c-major/id982291206?i=982291616&mt=1&app=music" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:musicDownloadLink]];
```